# Objective-C getting 0 out of mathematical calculation

Tags: objective-c

```
int desiredQuality = call.arguments[@"desiredQuality"]; //BETWEEN 0 AND 1602
float calculatedQuality = desiredQuality/1602; //RETURNS 0
```

Log:

```
APP: this is the desiredQuality: 802
APP: this is the calculatedQuality: 0.000000
```

I tried changing calculatedQuality to int, or double, but I get the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is `int` division

```
float calculatedQuality = desiredQuality/1602; //RETURNS 0
```

it will return 0 if number is less than 1602 , you need to convert it to

```
float calculatedQuality = desiredQuality/1602.0; //RETURNS 0.5
```

Comment: Damn, makes sense, thanks!